# Масштабирование элемента по скроллу на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Как написать функцию на чистом JS, чтобы картинка масштабировалась по скроллу.

```
<div class="block">
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос? Если необходимо то делайте

Comment: Необходимо написать функцию для масштабирования картинки

Answer (score 0):

Принцип понятен.

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  img.style.transform = `scale(${window.scrollY / 100 + 1})`;
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" alt="cat">
```